# implementing a container which has 6 divs inside equally spaced. Used display:inline-block, output is haphazard. Any suggestions?

Tags: html, css, svg

My code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/tewbaLnc/

HTML:

```
<div class="fields">
     <div class="block" >
<img class="fieldsvg" src="documentfields-icon.svg" alt="Document Fields" 
style="padding-top:10px">
    <br><br><br><br><h3 style="text-align:left;color:#525252;padding-left:10px;" >Div1</h3>
    <p style="color:#656565;text-align:left;padding-left:10px">Guide.</p> 
    </div> 
     <div class="block">
<img class="fieldsvg" src="templates-list-icon.svg" alt="Templates List"
style="padding-top:20px">
    <br>
    <br><br>
    <br><h3 style="text-align:left;color:#525252;padding-left:10px;padding-top:20px;" >Div2</h3>
    <p style="color:#656565;text-align:left;padding-left:10px">clicks.</p> 
    </div> 
     <div class="block">
    <img class="fieldsvg" src="tracking-icon.svg" alt="Tracking Icon"
    style="padding-top:20px">
    <br><br><br><br><h3 style="text-align:left;color:#525252;padding-left:10px;padding-top:20px;" >Div3</h3>
    <p style="color:#656565;text-align:left;padding-left:10px">Track.</p> 
    </div> 
      <div class="block">
    <img class="fieldsvg" src="routing-icon.svg" alt="Routing Icon"
    style="padding-top:20px">
    <br><br><br><br><h3 style="text-align:left;color:#525252;padding-left:10px;padding-top:20px;" >Div5</h3>
    <p style="color:#656565;text-align:left;padding-left:10px"> once.</p> 
    </div> 
     <div class="block">5. name of the company</div>
     <div class="block">6. name of the company</div>

</div>
```

CSS used:

```
img.fieldsvg{
    padding-left:10px;
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    float:left;}
div.fields{

    width: 100%;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    margin: 10px;
    position: relative;
    text-align:center;}
.block {
    background-color:white;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 25px;
}
```

The **HTML** is a little messy but easy to understand. Having a hard time figuring out what to do. I have tried adding `margin-top:-20px` to move the **Div1** up, but to no avail.

Is there anything else I could try? Since I am unable to find my mistake.

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have amended your fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tewbaLnc/1/)

What you need to do is add `vertical-align: top;` to the `.block` element like so:

```
.block {
  background-color: white;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 25px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Hey @RyanEarnshaw, I posted another question and have not got any solution so far. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46624841/trying-to-create-a-div-container-that-has-3-divs-within-it-topheader-leftf . Check it out if you have the time please.

Comment: @Yohanelly I had a look at it earlier but I will have another look now although I'm not quite sure I understand what you're asking on that question :) I will try my best tho

Comment: Its kind of difficult for me to explain. I uploaded a screenshot of the expected result in the question. As you can see it has a div for the header("Seamless integration...") and below two divs, LEFT and RIGHT. LEFT div is divided into 2 divs again. RIGHT div has an image.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `vertical-align: middle;` (for example `middle`) on your inline-block items (`.block`). Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tewbaLnc/2/

And a snippet:

```css
img.fieldsvg{
 padding-left:10px;
 width:80px;
 height:80px;
 float:left;}
div.fields{
 
 width: 100%;
   background: #f8f8f8;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
   text-align:center;}
.block {
 background-color:white;
   height: 300px;
   width: 300px;
   display:inline-block;
   margin: 25px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="fields">
     <div class="block" >
<img class="fieldsvg" src="documentfields-icon.svg" alt="Document Fields" 
style="padding-top:10px">
 <br><br><br><br><h3 style="text-align:left;color:#525252;padding-left:10px;" >Div1</h3>
 <p style="color:#656565;text-align:left;padding-left:10px">Guide.</p> 
 </div> 
     <div class="block">
<img class="fieldsvg" src="templates-list-icon.svg" alt="Templates List"
style="padding-top:20px">
 <br>
 <br><br>
 <br><h3 style="text-align:left;color:#525252;padding-left:10px;padding-top:20px;" >Div2</h3>
 <p style="color:#656565;text-align:left;padding-left:10px">clicks.</p> 
 </div> 
     <div class="block">
 <img class="fieldsvg" src="tracking-icon.svg" alt="Tracking Icon"
 style="padding-top:20px">
 <br><br><br><br><h3 style="text-align:left;color:#525252;padding-left:10px;padding-top:20px;" >Div3</h3>
 <p style="color:#656565;text-align:left;padding-left:10px">Track.</p> 
 </div> 
      <div class="block">
 <img class="fieldsvg" src="routing-icon.svg" alt="Routing Icon"
 style="padding-top:20px">
 <br><br><br><br><h3 style="text-align:left;color:#525252;padding-left:10px;padding-top:20px;" >Div5</h3>
 <p style="color:#656565;text-align:left;padding-left:10px"> once.</p> 
 </div> 
     <div class="block">5. name of the company</div>
     <div class="block">6. name of the company</div>
    
</div>
```

For more info about `vertical-align`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Comment: Thanks alot! It worked like a charm, didnt know I had to use the vertical-align.

Comment: Hi again, I would like to create a DivContainer which has 3 Divs inside it. One across the top (For the header), and the other two divided equally vertically.Any suggestions? I could show you a screenshot of what I am looking for if it helps.

Comment: never mind got it. I will be posting another question regarding JavaScript. I will try to do it using CSS first but I would like to try it using JS. Please have a look and help me out. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46624841/trying-to-create-a-div-container-that-has-3-divs-within-it-topheader-leftf I posted another question. Check it out if you have the time please.