# Trying to create a div-container that has 3 divs within it. Top(header) , Left(further divided into 2 Divs) and Right

Tags: html, css

The top, left and right divs are fine. But when I try to divide the left div into two divs, the right div (which has an image) is moving down.

HTML-

```
 <div style="width:100%">
<div style="width:100%;height:70px;text-align:center;">
<h3 style="color:#525252">Seamless integrations and flexible API</h3>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="floatleft">
    <div class="JShover">
    <h3 class="border">Works with your business applications
    <p >Connect with Office 365, GSuite.</p></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="JShover">
    <h3 class="border">Works with your business applications
    <p>Connect with Office 365, GSuite, Zoho, Dropbox and many more to let your teams sign documents without
    having to switch between applications.</p></h3></div>
    <div class="floatright">
    <img src="integrations-image.png" width="100%" height:"100px">
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;">
</div>
```

CSS-

```
.border{
    margin-left:300px;
    border-left:6px solid #3793EE;
    }
div.JShover{
    width:100%;
    height:50%;
    padding-left:-10px;
    text-align:center;
    }
.wrap {
    width: 100%;
}

.floatleft {
    float:left; 
    width: 50%;
    height: 400px;

}

.floatright {
float: right;
    height: 400px;
    width: 50%;
}
```

The JShover class is used to separate the LEFT Div into two equal halves. After creating these two halves, the RIGHT div (contains an image) moves down below the LEFT div instead of being to its side.

Can someone please help me out please.

Trying to achieve something similar to this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I have a solution for this that looks like your screenshot

[JSFiddle HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/vfmx6948/2/)

Your problem was that you hadn't closed all of the divs in the right places. Here is the amended code:

```
<div style="width:100%">   
  <div style="width:100%;height:70px;text-align:center;">
    <h3 style="color:#525252">Seamless integrations and flexible API</h3>   
  </div>   
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="floatleft">
      <div class="JShover">
        <h3 class="border">
          Works with your business applications
          <p >Connect with Office 365, GSuite.</p>
        </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="JShover">
        <h3 class="border">
          Works with your business applications
          <p>Connect with Office 365, GSuite, Zoho, Dropbox and many more to let your teams sign documents without having to switch between applications.</p>
        </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="floatright">
      <img src="integrations-image.png" width="100%" height="100">
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Obviously the text doesnt look exactly like the screenshot but thats because of the way you have created the border (the margin is pushing the text all the way to the right)

Hope this fixes it :)

Comment: Hey @RyanEarnshaw! Thanks alot man, that really helped. Now as you can see in the image, the text in the LEFT div is like fully visible (dont know the technical term) on hover. Would it be easier do to so in JS or CSS. And which one are you more versed in :)

Comment: @Yohanelly no problem man :)  yeah its do with opacity. i would recommend css like so: https://jsfiddle.net/vfmx6948/4/

Comment: And also, is it really tough in JS? Coz i really would like to learn it in both CSS and JS

Comment: @Yohanelly sorry for the slow reply. No absolutely not! In fact I would advise it in most cases. Theres lots of reallt nice JQuery things in here: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ The best way I find to learn is to think of what you want to achieve and then search for it online (i.e. JQuery how to mouse hover over element) and then you will pick up bits and pieces until eventually you'll know the whole library which is how I have learnt almost everything I know about coding :)

Comment: Okay so I have understood how to change the opacity of a div element by using javaScript. In the div element itself should I call onclick="document.getElementId('JShover').style.opacity="1"  is this the way? Thanks again @RyanEarnshaw :)

Comment: @Yohanelly its up to you really? Use what you find suitable. Do you want the element to be at full opacity when you click on it or when you hover on it? if you want it to only fully show when you click then use onClick otherwise use mouseUp and mouseDown events :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156219/discussion-between-yohanelly-and-ryan-earnshaw).

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of problems there:

1. padding-left cannot be negative
2. you are missing closing tag `</div>` before `floatright`
3. you don't need `width: 100%` in the `wrap` class since `div`s get expanded to the whole width of the page
4. `.border` shouldn't have `margin-left: 300px;`

Try this:

```css
html {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,:after,:before {
    box-sizing: inherit
}

.border{
  border-left:6px solid #3793EE;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 5%;
  }
div.JShover{
 height:50%;
 text-align: left;
}
.wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 1000px;
}
.floatleft {
    float:left; 
    width: 50%;
    height: 400px;  
}

.floatright {
    float: right;
    height: 400px;
    width: 50%;
}
```

```html
 <div class="wrap">
        <div class="floatleft">
     <div class="JShover">
     <h3 class="border">Works with your business applications
     <p >Connect with Office 365, GSuite.</p></h3>
     </div>
     <div class="JShover">
     <h3 class="border">Works with your business applications
     <p>Connect with Office 365, GSuite.</p></h3></div></div>
        <div class="floatright">
     <img src="https://stv.maps.yandex.net/images/?v=3.71.0&oid=1254556673_627919962_23_1465049772&z=3&x=0&y=0" width="100%" height="100px">
     </div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi, I added that but it made no difference. Have I made a mistake somewhere? My code: https://jsfiddle.net/h8b85jcd/  Please have a look, thanks for the help :)

Comment: hi! What I get on jsfiddle doesn't look like the screenshot you provided. Can you give me a link where you got the screenshot?

Comment: Actually this website is not live right now. I have a screenshot of the entire page which I can send to you. Yes, it is not the same at the moment. Cant find the error in my code though.

Comment: I have updated my answer. And paste an actual link to the image if you want to see it on the page.

Comment: Yes I tried it , the problem persists. Can I send you my code, but an error prior to this div should not have an effect on the current div correct?

Comment: what is the problem you are referring to? There are 2 blocks inside the left div and an image on the right. Nothing moves down as I see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156178/discussion-between-yohanelly-and-curveball).

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be your image might be too large to fit on the right side of the screen so it is dropping down below; but once it's below the other div, you can't tell it's too large as it is doing some weird re-sizing. Here is some working code where I used CSS to select the actual image inside your div to change its size and positioning. The image needs re-scaled so it will fit on the right side of your website. Hope this helps get you started as you will need to resize and position your image -next step.:)

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.border {
    margin-left:300px;
    border-left:6px solid #3793EE;
}
div.JShover {
    width:100%;
    height:50%;
    padding-left:-10px;
    text-align:center;
    display:none;    <!--- added code here -->
}
.wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.topheader {
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
}
.floatleft {
    float:left; 
    width: 50%;
    height: 400px;
    padding-right:50px;
    margin-right:100px;
}
.floatleft:hover div.JShover {   <!--- added code here -->
    display:block;
}
.floatright {
    position: absolute;
    align: right;
    height: 400px;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    top: 62px;
    right:20px;
}
.floatright img {
    width:85%
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="topheader"><h3>Seamless integrations and flexible API</h3></div>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="floatleft">
    <div class="JShover">
    <h3 class="border">Works with your business applications
    <p >Connect with Office 365, GSuite.</p></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="JShover">
    <h3 class="border">Works with your business applications
    <p>Connect with Office 365, GSuite.</p></h3></div>
    <div class="floatright">
    <img src="integrations-image.png" width="100%" height:"100px">
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Check it out here: http://larissaj.mywebcommunity.org/test.html

Comment: Hi I used this code, but the image is not showing at all and has increased the overall width of the page. The page now scrolls horizontally. Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: I added code to both floatleft, floatright, and floatright img. Did you copy the whole css ? Here is a site where I am running the code: http://larissaj.mywebcommunity.org/test.html

Comment: Please check that the image is in the same folder as your html file if you are getting a 404 error.

Comment: I tried it again copying your code. Same error as before, Is there any way I could show you my  code entirely? Maybe the div before this is causing an error, not entirely sure because I checked your link out and it worked.

Comment: Yes, you can update your question to add the rest of the code and then we can get it working. :)

Comment: I got it! thanks so much Larissa :) I'm actually trying to make the text in JShover (the left div with the text) appear on hover using JavaScript or CSS. Are you familiar with this?

Comment: Hi Yohanelly, that's great! I updated the site: larissaj.mywebcommunity.org/test.html and edited my answer. By adding display: none to your JSHover div and then display:block to the parent div's hover css, the jshover divs will not show until the user hovers over the parent div. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! Yes i will check it out and let you know :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156204/discussion-between-yohanelly-and-larissa-j).